# How can prevent Stored XSS by iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, xss

I use Extjs and JS to build a dialog where can display my html data from DB, that data is wrapped with `iframe` like this:

```html
<iframe name="ext-gen568" frameborder="0" src="javascript:;" style="width: 514px; height: 189px;">
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
<br><br>
<blockquote type="cite"> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <video><source src="x" onerror="alert('xss')"></video>
</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I tried to add `sandbox` to `iframe`, but it doesn't work, the XSS alert still show.

- Then I tried to change to  `<iframe src='#'... sandbox>`, but XSS alert still show.
- I removed `src` or just set it `''` in `<iframe src=''... sandbox>`, it got this error: `DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "mytestdomain" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

What should I do to handle my issue?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: You're going to need to whitelist tags and do it that way.

Comment: @Brad, I don't really get your idea. Can you explain more, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed by set "allow-same-origin" for sandbox

```html
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin" src="javascript:;"...></iframe>
```